# How to invoke manually fixures in conftest

Tags: python, scope, pytest, fixtures, conftest

in my piece of code had several fixures which is running in session scope, and some fixure that is running each test (autouse=true) which is checking some condition and if the condition is true than call again to fixure which is in this case defined as session scope.
does it possible to do?

P.S
**this piece of code is just a sample**

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def init_list():
    grate = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    print("A")
    return grate


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def get_A_grate(init_list):
    return init_list[0]

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_again(get_A_grate):
    if get_A_grate == 'A':
        **init_list()**
```

Comment: Just pass the fixture additionally to `init_again` - it will be executed only once anyway.

Comment: I need the init_list wil execute when the session starts, and when the if condition is true,
not in each test the the "if get_A_grate == 'A':' , when when it true invoke again init_list():

Comment: You can't call a fixture directly. In this case you have to move the initialization code into a normal function which is called from both fixtures.